# How can we use asp mvc kendo file upload and returning Kendo notification?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, notifications, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to upload a file using telerik asp mvc product. After file upload, I want to show kendo notification but since I can't call ajax method from controller I'm having a trouble doing this, any help?

Comment: Would you like the message to appear after or before the page POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the message in the `TempData`

```
TempData["KendoMsg"] = String.Format("{0} has been saved",model.fileName);
```

And in the returning view

```
@section scripts{
   <script>
      $(function(){
          if(@TempData["KendoMsg"] != ""){
              popupNotification.show(@TempData["KendoMsg"]);
          }
      });
   </script>
}
```

And if you are not waiting for the POST then you can just use the

```
<script>
$("#files").kendoUpload({
    async: {
        saveUrl: "save",
        removeUrl: "remove"
    },
    success: onSuccess
});

function onSuccess(e) {
    // Array with information about the uploaded files
    var files = e.files;

    if (e.operation == "upload") {
        popupNotification.show("Successfully uploaded " + files.length + " files");
    }
}
</script>
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload#events-success